# How to connect Spark-Notebook to Hive metastore?

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, cloudera-cdh, spark-notebook, apache-spark-1.2

This is a cluster with Hadoop 2.5.0, Spark 1.2.0, Scala 2.10, provided by CDH 5.3.2. I used a [compiled spark-notebook distro](http://spark-notebook.io)

It seems Spark-Notebook cannot find the Hive metastore by default.

How to specify the location of `hive-site.xml` for spark-notebook so that it can load the Hive metastore?

Here is what I tried:

1. link all files from /etc/hive/conf, with hive-site.xml included, to the current directory
2. specify SPARK_CONF_DIR variable in bash

Comment: Have you already hive metastore services started?

Answer (score 1):

When you start the notebook set the environment variable EXTRA_CLASSPATH with the path where you have located the hive-site.xml, 
this works for me:`EXTRA_CLASSPATH=/path_of_my_mysql_connector/mysql-connector-java.jar:/my_hive_site.xml_directory/conf ./bin/spark-notebook`
I have also passed the jar of my mysqlconnector because I have Hive with MySql.

I have found some info from this link: https://github.com/andypetrella/spark-notebook/issues/351

Answer (score 0):

Using CDH 5.5.0 Quickstart VM, the solution is the following: You need the reference `hive-site.xml`to the notebook which provides the access information to the hive metastore. By default, spark-notebooks uses an internal metastore.

You can the define the following environmental variable in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_CONF_DIR:/etc/hive/conf.cloudera.hive/
export HADOOP_CON_DIR
```

(Make sure you execute `source ~/.bash_profile` if you do not open a new terminal the terminal)

(The solution is given here: https://github.com/andypetrella/spark-notebook/issues/351)